# How to prevent default image download while using drag and drop in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

This example in javascript, I am expectino output in angular

```
<img ondragleave="abc()" src="google.png" />

  function abc(){
    console.log("1");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How to prevent default image download while using drag and drop in angular -- This is what I am expecting

Comment: Please provide the proper explanation

Comment: event.preventDefault() is what you need most likely. It'd be better if your question was more detailed. But I am certain that's what you probably need. ondragleave="abc($event)" and then preventDefault on the passed event in abc function.